# Directory.EnumerateFiles hangs with disk pegged to 100%

Tags: unity, c#, windows, .net

I am having an issue that occurs seemingly at random with the following block of code.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSavedGameFileList()
    {
        foreach (string fullFilePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Application.persistentDataPath, "*.save"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Located save game: " + fullFilePath);
            yield return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFilePath);
        }
    }
```

Unity will freeze and force me to close it. There is no error message, in the Windows Task Manager, I noticed that the disk utilization gets pegged at or near 100%:

[image: Task manager window with Unity consuming 100% of disk throughput]

Nothing is logged to the console when this happens. The folder it's scanning only contains 3-5 files during my testing. I am running Unity 2017.2.0f3 with the .NET 4.6 backend.

Here is what I have tried without success:

- Use `Directory.GetFiles` instead of `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.
- Storing my results in intermediate arrays instead of returning an `IEnumerable`.
- Restarting the Unity editor.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: disk at 100% can be another Windows 7 unrelated issue. Does disk usage go down when you kill your task? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712888/disk-is-always-running-at-100-windows-10, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133744/visual-studio-100-disk-usage)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the suggestion. I'll investigate that avenue. I'm developing on Windows 10, by the way. And yes, the disk usage returns to normal levels when I kill the Unity task.

Comment: then my links are probably not that useful. I would try to put a breakpoint in this piece of code and see what happens there. What are the values of the variables, etc...